# How do I change streaming buffer size in iTunes 10.5?

Tags: windows, itunes, streaming

I want to change the buffering of streaming radio in iTunes 10.5.  Every help document I've found online says to go to `Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced Tab`.  I see no such buffer option there.  I'm running on Windows XP Service Pack 3.

Comment: I really hope they add the buffer option back - it's really useful in controlling the smoothness to real-time-ness (if that's a word) ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall seeing it there once upon a time.  It appears they've removed this option.

Comment: Thanks.  Bummer.  Using Windows Media Player for streaming radio it is.